# Sort collections of docs By the biggest embedded Doc with mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema with mongoose

```
schema = new Schema({
    id: {
      type: String,
    },
   embedded: [embeddedSchema]
});

embeddedSchema = new Schema({
    value: {
        type: String,
    },
});
```

This can produce something like :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5454f4f1073cc3b529320f79"),
    "embedded" : [ 
        {
            "value" : 123,

        }    ,        {
            "value" : 123,

        },
        {
            "value" : 123423,

        }
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5454f508910ef3b82970f11d"),
    "embedded" : [ 
        {
            "value" : 1,

        }     ,       {
            "value" : 2,

        },
        {
            "value" : 9999999,

        }]
}
```

I would like to sort the schema collection by the biggest value of embedded doc.
Which query can produce this kind of result ?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you sort descending on an array element field like `value`, MongoDB uses the maximum value of that field among all elements in the array.

So in this case it would be:

```
MyModel.find().sort('-embedded.value').exec(callback);
```